# Partial polygon matching

Tags: pattern-matching, polygon, computational-geometry

I am looking for fast procedures for polygon matching, i.e. checking polygon similarity under different transforms

- translation only,
- translation + rotation,
- translation + scaling,
- translation + rotation + scaling (= similarity).

The matching can be partial, meaning that there can be a good match on a significant fraction of the outline (say > 70%), and complete mismatch elsewhere.

The number of vertices is reasonable (say N<50).

In a variant of the problem, you need to compare two polygons. In another variant, you compare one polygon to a series of polygons, with preprocessing of the single polygon allowed.

Are you aware of solutions to this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  Original article came from Berkeley [Original Article](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Optimization/Combinatorialpapers/iccv01.pdf)

A great place to start is with this great article from Stanford
 [Shape Matching and object recognition Using Shape Contexts](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-08-fall/pdf/belongie-pami02.pdf)

The article contains many different types of pattern matching (brightness-based, graphed methods), and mathematical formulas to go with it.  Most of the formulas evaluate a given image point by point.

You may need to compare a 'snapshot' of your polygon instead of traversing it with a turtle type algo that traces and records the angles of the polygon.

Comment: Yep, that's an interesting reference. As I see, they build point descriptors around every "vertex" and use the descriptors to solve the correspondence problem.

Comment: Yes!  I know this is not the kind of answer you were looking for, but you might have to build the engine from scratch!

Comment: I don't mind starting from scratch and I am open to all suggestions. I like the idea of the descriptors (the can be made similarity-invariant I guess), which will work if it is discriminant enough.

Comment: You can come up with methods that allow you to tweak the precision the algo uses, like maybe passing in the number of points to compare.  If the matching is not being accurate enough, bump up the points. If it's taking too long, cut it down.

Comment: @YvesDaoust have you had any luck with my answer?  Keep me in the loop with your research.

Comment: I am still looking for bibliographical sources. The "point descriptor" approach does not take into account missing or additional parts.

Comment: Couldn't you just set a threshold for the amount of points that are identical?  If you wanted both images to be at least 70% identical, have the checker method return true if NumberOfIdentical / TotalNumberOfChecks >= 0.70.

Comment: When you compute the descriptor, you don't know which points will be identical.

Comment: That's not necessary.  All you need to to do is increment an int when a point is found to be identical.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something.. can you post the code that you have so far?

Comment: Code, what code ? The descriptors are computed on a single polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms and methods for matching and computing distances between shapes can be classified roughly based on the *locality* of the features considered.

*I would try to list some, to the best of my knowledge, Try searching for the keywords below*

1. Some use differential properties of shapes (*curvature-scale-space transform, ...*)
2. Or a radial histogram of points (*shape-contexts* as mentioned in the answer by user1487195)
3. Statistical approaches (*Image moments, zernike moments*)
4. *Fourier descriptors*
5. *Integral invariants*

In general many of the methods will calculate (and may be store) some kind of a shape signature which is simpler than the shape itself also invariant to transformations/occlusion etc. (in case of shape-contexts this is the histogram). Then a matching phase would follow.

In my experience, the most time consuming part of the method of shape-contexts is matching, the signature is calculated rather easily. In matching (or for calculating distance) you need to find a good correspondence between the sampled points by using something similar to *Hungarian method* combined with *thin-plate spline transformation*. This might take some time if you have a large database of shapes.

I would recommend trying out Integral invariants. In your case it may be easier than it looks in the papers linked, if you are only dealing with polygons (as opposed to curves).

[Integral Invariants for Shape Matching](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.8044&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Integral Invariant Signatures](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a479522.pdf)

There is no overall "best" method, only the ones that may suit your needs better. This is because different algorithms have different characteristics. For example methods that *depend* on more local features has an issue with sensitivity to noise, but may be better at recognising occluded shapes.

So I think you might want to send some time with each of the classes of algorithm (the list above is definitely not exhaustive) studying their characteristics.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing shape recognition for robotic machine vision back in the 70's, when we used an algorithm attributed to Heginbotham and Pugh, as follows:
Find the center of gravity (centroid) of an object, then overlay a fixed number of circles on the object from the center to the minimum circumcircle. (Lets say 8 circles for an example, though the number is arbitrary.) Also overlay the object with a fixed number of radii, equally spaced in a star-like patterns - the number of radii defined by the convenient bit size of a machine word (which in today's world might be 64 - we used 32).  Sample the 8 x 32 points where the radii and circles intersect and return as 8 machine words.  Do the same for your target object, and compare by comparing bitmasks and counting the number of bits that match.  Then do a cyclic shift of your bitmasks and compare again until all 32 angles have been tried.  This satisfies your constraint of being both rotation independent and scale independent.

In the world of polygons, a simpler but more expensive algorithm might be:
Find centroid.  Scale target polygon so that its cirumcircle matches the test objects circumcircle.  Rotate target polyon through a whole circle by however many steps you feel comfortable with.  Do an AND operation between the two polygons and record the parameters of the one with the greatest matching area.  As a refinement possibly repeat the algorithm between the best match angle and its two neighbours using a smaller step to fine-tune the result.

The only downside of this algorithm in your case is that you do allow objects with some features added or removed, in which case the center of gravity could be significantly displaced - whether this is a problem for you or not will depend on the details and degree of these tacked-on features.  Perhaps you could come up with a better choice for the center point, perhaps by discarding the most eccentric single feature that sticks out?

PS Note if comparing a single target against multiple objects, it's more efficient to scale and rotate your target than the objects you are comparing it with, because you can cache those translations and rotations and re-use them.